# FFMPEG script to merge all files in a list and make a 1920x1080p 60fps mp4 video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have a list of 46 videos in a text file. I tried the concat method to merge all of them, which worked but the quality is very poor and the audio is bugged/missing at parts.

 Can someone please help me with a script to merge all 46 videos and the output to be 1920x1080 60fps mp4 video?

Comment: *"quality is very poor and the audio is bugged/missing at parts"* Seems like the files have different attributes. They all need to be the same for proper concatenation. Showing your command and the complete log would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to scale all your videos, you can use a script like this in the directory with only the videos .Presuming they have different formats making all off the same format could make things easy.

```
for i in *;
   do name= echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1
   echo "$name"
   ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v copy -c:a copy -pixel_format yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -async 1 "${name}.mp4"
```

(Or

```
ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v h264 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -pixel_format yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -async 1 "${name}.mp4"
```

If you have still problems with audio.)

the -r force the frame rate of each video to 60 by multiplying the frames;
check the quality of the video and the audio, do your list and then:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy concat.mp4
```